# Several translation joins in sql

Tags: sql, select

A primary table holds info about things with int id's.

Translations for these id's are in second table. Id of second table refers to primary table id's, and holds textual description of these. I need a hint how to write a sql select clause to get all the fields from primary table so that all its id values are shown as translation texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Table1 have id1, id2, id3 and table2 the translations, I will do something like that (not tested):

```
Select T1.ID1, T1.ID2, T1.ID3, T21.Translation as Name1, T22.Translation  as Name2, T23.Translation  as Name3,
from Table1 T1 left join Table2 T21 on T1.Id1 = T21.Table1_ID
   left join Table2 T22 on T1.Id2 = T22.Table1_ID
   left join Table2 T23 on T1.Id3 = T23.Table1_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
select table1.*, table2.description from table1, table2 
where table1.id = table2.id;
```

Comment: that's just one join? I mean, the fields in primary table are like thing1_id, thing2_id and so on.

Comment: @mjgirl It would be useful if you could provide us with minimal representative example of how your tables look. Ben Clifford's answer is correct in the context of your question, but it seems you are actually trying to ask a different question!

Comment: you can write a longer join, with one join per column. I can see that getting pretty long quite fast though: select j1.description, j2.description from table1, table2 as j1, table2 as j2, where j1.id=table1.thing1_id, j2.id=table1.thing2_id